# General solution of a linear nonhomogeneous equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I was doing a question on finding the general solution of a linear nonhomogeneous function and I was given a solution. But I don't understand the third line of the particular solution bit. Can someone help explain this to me?[image]

---

$$
\frac{d^6 y}{dx^6} - 2 \frac{d^5y}{dx^5} + \frac{d^4 y}{dx^4} = e^x + e^{2x}
$$
We can write it in the form
$$
\left(D^6 - 2D^5 +D^4 \right)y = e^x + e^{2x}
$$
with $D= \frac{d}{dx}$. Let $y=e^{mx}\neq 0$ be the trivial solution. Therefore, the auxiliary equation is
$$
\begin{align}
& m^6 - 2m^5 + m^4 = 0 \\
&\Rightarrow m^4 \left(m^2 - 2m +1 \right) = 0 \\
&\Rightarrow m^4 \left(m-1 \right)^2 = 0 \\
&\Rightarrow m = 0, +1, +1
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, CF is
$$
y = C_1  + (C_2 + c_3 x)e^x
$$
where $c_1$, $c_2$ and $c_3$ are arbitrary constants. Now
$$
\begin{split}
PI &= \frac{1}{D^4 (D-1)^2} \left(e^x + e^{2x} \right) \\
   &= \frac{1}{D^4 (D-1)^2} e^x + \frac{1}{D^4 (D-1)^2}e^{2x} \\
   &= e^x \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{e^{2x}}{16}
\end{split}
$$
Therefore, the required general solution is 
$$
\begin{split}
y &= CF + PI \\
& = C_1  + (C_2 + c_3 x)e^x + e^x \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{e^{2x}}{16}
\end{split}
$$
where $c_1$, $c_2$ and $c_3$ are the arbitrary constants.

Comment: Your homogeneous solution is incomplete. Remember that the root $m=0$ has a multiplicity of $4$

Comment: Thank you, but my main issue is with the particular solution as I don't understand the steps that take the second line to the third :)